# z-index collapse menu bootstrap 4 CSS not work properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a slide in the bootstrap 4 menus that are working well but will not take care of the z-index value I set for it.
In particular, I have this problem with some content that is inside a parallax jumbotron and is showed overlapped to the menu links. I need a CSS way to fix this, it's the first time that I have this problem.
Here is the code I'm using, I will post the parallax jumbotron one and the code related to the menu. I think that I've messed up with the code to apply an overlay effect on the background image that is under the content that is causing the issue.

CSS:

```
.st-parallax{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.parallax{
  filter: grayscale(100);
}
.parallax__container{
  z-index: 1;
}
.parallax-icon, .parallax-heading, .parallax-text {
  color: white;
}
.parallax-content {
  margin: 12em 0 4em 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.overlay{
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#bs-nav {
    transition: all 300ms;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: white;
}
#navbar-content {
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0
}
.navbar-collapse {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: white;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    -webkit-transition: left .3s ease;
    -o-transition: left .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: left .3s ease;
    transition: left .3s ease;
    left: -100%
}
.navbar-collapse.show {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: left .3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: left .3s ease-in;
    transition: left .3s ease-in
}
```

PARALLAX HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid st-parallax">
  <div class="parallax" data-parallax-image="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/assets/img/staff-heading.jpg" data-bg="url(<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/assets/img/staff-heading.jpg)"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 parallax-content">
        <h4 class="parallax-icon hide"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i></h4>
        <h1 class="parallax-heading hide"><?php _e('staff'); ?></h1>
        <p class="lead parallax-text hide"><?php _e('lorem ipsum.'); ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

MENU HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

  <div class="preloader text-center">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/assets/img/logo-black.jpg" width="300" id="preloader-img" />
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar fixed-top shadow-lg" id="bs-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="z-index:4;">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
          <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/logo-black.jpg" id="" width="80" height="80">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 float-right">
          <button class="hamburger hamburger--spin" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expand="false" aria-label="<?php _e('Toggle Navigation'); ?>">
            <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
            </span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                    'menu'        => 'Menu',
                    'container'      => false,
                    'depth'          => 2,
                    'menu_class'     => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                    'walker'         => new Bootstrap_NavWalker(),
                    'fallback_cb'    => 'Bootstrap_NavWalker::fallback',
                ) );
              ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Here is a screen of the issue, you can see on the portfolio link the parallax content that is a white text.
[image]

Comment: try adding css position:relative; to every element where you have z-index

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, I was assigning the z-index to the wrong container to let the parallax background image display. I've assigned the z-index value to the `jumbotron` parallax container and now the issue is solved.

```
.st-parallax{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```